# How do take an existing map and overlay it into google maps on the android platform?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on making a interactive campus map.  I am wanting to take an image (below) and overlay it onto Google maps and then add interactive points of interests.   I am not seeing how to add or merge the image to the map.  Can this be done? Are there any examples out there I missed?

[image: Campus map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the google map background.
From my experience, I could say no. It can't be done

But if you want to make it like transparent you can put Your map on top of google map and just set transparent.

However, somebody already been done this before. you might got some idea if you see this

http://www.maplib.net/

http://lifehacker.com/213627/embed-any-image-into-a-google-map

Comment: I am not seeing how to do this in Android as I do not see a groundOverlay feature that google maps uses for HTML.

Answer (score -1):

[Google Maps Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)